# boundary conditions of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Suppose that I have a differential equation

$f''(x) = \mathcal{L}_1 (f)$

where $\mathcal{L}$ is an operator acting on $f$, with the solutions known in closed form.

Then I am trying to numerically solve the problem for $x\in[0,R]$

$f''(x) = \mathcal{L}_1(f) + g(x)\mathcal{L}_2(f)$

where now $g(x)$ is a known function and $\mathcal{L}_2$ is another operator acting on $f$. Given that

$\lim_{x\to0}g(x) =0$,

would it make sense to say that close to the origin $x=0$, the numerical solution would behave the same as the analytical solution (i.e. when $g(x)=0$)? In that case, the initial conditions near the origin can be given by the values of the analytical solutions.

Comment: I can't think on any counterexample now, but if $g(x)$ is well-behaved, $\mathcal{L}_2(f(0))$ is not infinity, etc., you can assume that both solutions share the same behavior in the origin.